# Eclipse plugin to view image while debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin, bufferedimage

Is there an Eclipse plugin that will let me view an image variable while I'm paused at a breakpoint?  e.g. I would like to see the image when inspecting a BufferedImage object instead of seeing it's toString value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension point `org.eclipse.jdt.debug.javaLogicalStructures` is used to provide the structured view of variables in the "Variables" view... and unfortunately it can only give you a string based result.

In theory, you can add a new plug-in which adds a new command to the "Variables" view (the selection is of type `JDILocalVariable`)...